# Calling a sub api call with the response of first

Tags: python, zendesk

I have the following code which saves to a log file. However this log file only contains the link url to the status of the batch, so I need to call the log a second time to get this status from my first call. So this code below works great, but the response data looks like this. I need to grab the URL and get the response of that into my log as well. Is this possible without massive code bloat? Or would it be better to do a second script that reads my file and grabs these?

{"job_status":{"id":"1e36718398bd0f6a8cabe58befe6c292","url":"https://myurl.foo.com/api/v2/job_statuses/1e36718398bd0f6a8cabe58befe6c335.json","total":null,"progress":null,"status":"queued","message":null,"results":null}}

```
for payload in payloads:
    print(payload)


for payload in payloads:
    response = session.post(url, data=payload)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Failure Message {}' .format(response.text))
        exit()
    print('Successfully imported a batch of users {}' .format(response.text))
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more of what you are trying to accomplish? why loop through payloads twice like that?

Comment: The API creates a response with a Que, you then need to hit the que url to get the actual status of the batch. Its their api so trying to make this with one script vs 2

Comment: Let me see if I understand entirely, you want to get the "url" field from data you have in your question? (i.e. `"https://myurl.foo.com/api/v2/job_statuses/1e36718398bd0f6a8cabe58befe6c335.json"`)

Comment: Yes that is part of the response from the first payload. I then need to hit that url from the response to get the actual status of the batch itself.